# How to check write permissions of a directory in java?

Tags: java

I would like a code snippet that checks whether a directory has read/write permissions and do something if it does, and does something else if it doesnt. I tried an example shown here:

```
try {
    AccessController.checkPermission(new FilePermission("/tmp/*", "read,write"));
System.out.println("Good");
    // Has permission
} catch (SecurityException e) {
    // Does not have permission
System.out.println("Bad");
}
```

The problem is the  exception is always triggered, so it always ends up printing "Bad" regardless of whether the directory has write permissions or not. (I chmod the directories to 777 or 000 to test).

Is there an alternative or some way to accomplish what I need?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

if you just want to check if you can write:

```
File f = new File("path");
if(f.canWrite()) {
  // write access
} else {
  // no write access
}
```

for checking read access, there is a function `canRead()`

Comment: f.canWrite fails in network path for example:- "\\abc123\canwrite". If i dont have the permission to write in this directory its not returning me the correct value.

Comment: This isn't the correct answer. Check the solution from Robert Niestroj

Comment: @Asu Why it is not correct? I know that Files API is newer, but should not file.canWrite and Files.isWritable return same result?

Comment: @Wortig It has been a while since I had looked at it, but from what I can remember, this method just wasn't always reliable (sometimes it gives a wrong response).

Answer (score 47):

In Java **7** i do it like this:

```
if(Files.isWritable(path)){
  //ok, write
}
```

[Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#isWritable%28java.nio.file.Path%29)

Comment: The doc only mentions files. Does it work for directories ? Does it work on network paths ?

Comment: The argument is a `Path` so it should not matter wheter it is a File or Directory.

Comment: This checks if a _File_ is writable, but returns false if the file does not exist. So this will not work for this use case; if you do successfully write a file, then the .isWritable() check becomes sort of redundant.

Comment: It will not work if the file under path does not exist, documentation does not mention directories at all

Comment: From a *nix perspective: directories are also just files...

Answer (score 12):

You should use the path of the directory alone (`"/tmp"`) to query the permissions of a directory:

```
AccessController.checkPermission(new FilePermission("/tmp", "read,write"));
```

With `"/tmp/*"` you query the permissions of all files inside the `/tmp` directory.

Comment: Always i have exception java.security.AccessControlException: access denied, i create my owner directory/file with all permission

Comment: AccessController is deprecated and marked for removal

Answer (score 7):

Java has its own permission model revolving around the use of an `AccessController` and `Permission` classes. The permissions are granted to a code source (the location from where the classes are loaded), and in some/most cases these permissions are different from any underlying permissions required to access the desired resource.

For instance, although you may have granted all users to read and write to the `/tmp` directory, this isn't sufficient for the AccessController to grant your code the necessary permission. You'll also need to add a rule in the policy file used (by the AccessController) to read and write files from the /tmp directory. The rule to be created will be equivalent to the following:

```
grant codeBase "<location of the codebase>" {
    permission java.io.FilePermission "/tmp/-", "read, write";
};
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work fine:

```
assertFalse(Files.isWritable(new File("/etc/").toPath()));
assertTrue(Files.isWritable(new File("/tmp/").toPath()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to check permissions for **folder** or for **files in folder**?

"/*" in path name means a directory and all the files contained in that directory.

[see javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilePermission.html#FilePermission%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

`java.io.File` has two methods [`canRead`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#canRead%28%29) and [`canWrite`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#canWrite%28%29) that should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

```java
if(DocumentFile.fromFile(file).canWrite()){
   //allowed
   ...
}else{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, File.canWrite() does not always provide an accurate result. I would recommand using the following:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
...

if(Files.isWritable(Paths.get("path"))){
  //ok, write
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oops, one more thing. The directory also has to be executable, at least on linux:

```
  /** Make sure output dir exists and is writeable. */
  public boolean validateOutputDir(Path publishDirectory, Formatter error) {
    if (!Files.exists(publishDirectory)) {
      error.format(" Output directory '%s' does not exist%n", publishDirectory);
      return false;
    }
    if (!Files.isDirectory(publishDirectory)) {
      error.format(" Output directory '%s' is not a directory%n", publishDirectory);
      return false;
    }
    if (!Files.isWritable(publishDirectory)) {
      error.format(" Output directory '%s' is not writeable%n", publishDirectory);
      return false;
    }
    if (!Files.isExecutable(publishDirectory)) {
      error.format(" Output directory '%s' is not executable%n", publishDirectory);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```