# Unable to create new directory in documents or Program Files in Java

Tags: java

I apologize in advance if this is nooby, however I am new to dealing with files that are not in the same directory as the jar.

I'm unable to create new directory in documents or Program Files using the following:

```
private JSONObject readSaveFile() { // line 17
    File file;

    String programPath = new JFileChooser().getFileSystemView().getDefaultDirectory().toString();
    System.out.println(programPath);
    if (programPath != null) {
        System.out.println(new File(programPath + "/HWFetcherSave").mkdir());
        programPath += "/HWFetcherSave/data.json";
        file = new File(programPath);
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
            //TODO log error

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JSONObject jsonObject = JSONUtils.readFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

        if (jsonObject == null) jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        return jsonObject;
    }
    return null;
}
```

And the trace:

```
C:\Users\Ethan\Documents
false
java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1006)
    at HomeworkFetcher.readSaveFile(HomeworkFetcher.java:27)
    at HomeworkFetcher.main(HomeworkFetcher.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Ethan\Documents\HWFetcherSave\data.json (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
The specified path could not be used to find a file.
    at JSONUtils.readFile(JSONUtils.java:58)
    at HomeworkFetcher.readSaveFile(HomeworkFetcher.java:32)
    at HomeworkFetcher.main(HomeworkFetcher.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

What I'm really trying to do is save data to a location other than the desktop, however it seems that I can't do this. Anyone know something I don't?

By request, the static method in JsonUtils

```
public static JSONObject readFile(String path) {
        try {
            return readFile(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path)));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("The specified path could not be used to find a file.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

public static JSONObject readFile(BufferedReader reader) {
        try {
            return (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(reader);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to parse file.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Try mkdirs() instead of mkdir().

Comment: @rsutormin no change.

Comment: If it doesn't help then make sure you have write priviledge for the folder where you're trying to make subfolder in.

Comment: @rsutormin I don't, which is what the real issue is. I can't really figure out how to get the privilege.

Comment: It's more like a windows issue rather than java one.

Comment: One sec. i'll compile this into a jar instead of using IntelliJ's console. EDIT: Confirmed. No change.

Comment: There are many reasons you are unable to create the directory at first. On windows, if a file exits with the directory name you are trying to create, it will not support. Hence before you do `new File(programPath + "/HWFetcherSave").mkdir()`, check `new File(programPath + "/HWFetcherSave").exists()`. Moreover, try to print the path `programPath + "/HWFetcherSave"` to see if you have extra slashes.

Comment: @James comes out false with both code and checking the file explorer. And nope: C:\Users\Ethan\Documents/HWFetcherSave/data.json

Comment: @EthanZ, why don't you do a permission check before yo ugo to write into the directory as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/6231840/584420

Comment: @JamesJithin, brand new to being in areas where I need to check for permission. I'm trying that now.  EDIT: access denied for both.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following? :

```
JSONObject jsonObject = JSONUtils.readFile(file);
```

I don't know the version of the library which contains JSONUtils class, but i think its method "readFile" must have the file as parameter instead the path of the file.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I wrote JsonUtils. One second. Also, the real issue is that I cannot create the directory, not reading the contents of file.

Comment: I have tried this code and in my case it works. But when the directory is created, printing the result of "mkdir()" will be false anyways.

Comment: Added in the JsonUtil methods, also, the file refuses to write, so it works for now.