# How to differentiate between a network path and absolute path and read a file from network path in java

Tags: windows, file, java-8, file-io

I have a field where a user can specify an absolute path or network path.[image]

In the Excel Folder Path user can give an absolute path or network path.

**Absolute Path -> C:\ExcelExtractor**

**Network Path -> file://LAPTOP-83N1BUOI/Users/d_avi/OneDrive/Documents**

**Also will the network path start with file : or will it start with // or \**

In my java code i get the value of Excel Folder Path

Here is my sample java code.

```
public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        File file = new File("file://LAPTOP-83N1BUOI/Users/d_avi/OneDrive/Documents");

        String fileName = file.getName();

        System.out.println("Is file " + file.isFile()); 
        System.out.println("Directory " + file.isDirectory());
        System.out.println("Absolute " + file.isAbsolute());
        System.out.println("fileName is " + fileName);
        System.out.println("Can Read " + file.canRead());
        System.out.println("Can Write " + file.canWrite());

        File file1 = new File("D:\\File Testing");
        System.out.println("Directory" + file1.isDirectory());
        System.out.println("Absolute" + file1.isAbsolute());

    }
```

**Here is the output of the code**

```
Is file false -> this condition is clear, because the path given is till a folder
Directory false
Absolute false
fileName is Documents
Can Read false
Can Write false

Directory true
Absolute true
```

I have given all the sharing and permissions to the Documents folder, but still isDirectory() returns false, canRead() returns false, canWrite () returns false.

I agree with the condition Is file returning false because the path is given till a directory

Need help and suggestions on the following

**- How to decide whether it is network path**

**- How to read a file from network path**

**- How to create a new folder in network path and copy a file to that folder**

Comment: Why do you want to know this? Do you know network paths can be mapped to a drive letter as well?

Comment: @CodeCaster I am supposed to read a file from a network path, so want to know this. I am not sure how to map network path to a drive letter.

Comment: My point is that your code should not care whether a path points to a disk or a network. Why do you want to know where it points to?

Comment: @CodeCaster There are multiple points here
1. If it is network path i need to check whether i have permission to that folder and file
2. Once my file is processed i need to a create a new folder in that path and make a copy of the processed file to the new folder created.

Comment: 3. If it is absolute path i do a check in my code if the last character ends with "/" or "\" and if not i try to append "/" or "\". This check will not work for network path and it will try to append '/" or '\".

if (folderPath.indexOf("\\") != -1) {
     folderPath = folderPath.endsWith("\\") ? folderPath : folderPath + "\\";

    } else {
     folderPath = folderPath.endsWith("/") ? folderPath : folderPath + "/";
    }

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412380/how-to-combine-paths-in-java, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231779/how-to-check-write-permissions-of-a-directory-in-java Again, you do not need to know (you literally should not care) whether a path points to a network.

Comment: @CodeCaster one more question 
Also will the network path start with file : or will it start with // or \
file://LAPTOP-83N1BUOI/Documents
//LAPTOP-83N1BUOI/Documents
Can this be treated as network path file://LAPTOP-83N1BUOI/Documents ?

Comment: Java's APIs do not really care about where you are reading data from as long as the URI is correct.

Comment: A `File` is not a `URL`. Passing a URL to the `File` constructor just creates an invalid `File` object. That’s why all methods return `false`. If you want to access a URL, you have to use the `URL` class. But there isn’t a standard for accessing `file:` URLs on a different computer anyway. If you want to access a Windows share on a Windows computer, use Window’s network file syntax, i.e. `\\LAPTOP-83N1BUOI\Users\d_avi\OneDrive\Documents`.